# How to full screen a PDF having more than one slide per page

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader, slideshow

The problem I'm facing is that I have PDFs that are made of 4 slides per page, when I try to full screen it, I have to zoom in the upper-left, upper-right corners in order to view the wanted slide..

[image]

I know thats possible, because teachers in my uni use PDFs having that structure.

Thanks

Comment: I have been in a university for many years and the teachers use to upload a PDF with 4 slides per page to facilite printing and in the classes they use a 1 slide per page version.

If I were you I will ask for the 1 slide per page version.

Comment: Your question is confusing.  Are you trying to full-screen the PDF or one of the component slides?  BTW, what you're showing is a handout view produced from a presentation.  The individual slides are shown during the presentation.  This view is just a compact way to reduce pages for the handouts.  As Angel Sanchis suggests, a simple solution is to just request the original presentation, or a PDF generated one slide per page.

Answer (score 2):

#### Workaround

You can convert your PDF file, splitting it in a convenient way.
An easy tool can be `mutool`

```
mutool poster -x 2 -y 2 input.pdf output.pdf
```

<sup>Note: It is released with the [Affero GPL licence](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html), one of the GNU licences, so open source, you can [read on wiki too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affero_General_Public_License)...)</sup>

---

Under Linux mutool is installed with the [**mupdf**](http://www.mupdf.com/) package.
You can [**download**](http://www.mupdf.com/downloads/) the source code or the compiled one for the other OS (windows, android, apple...).
In Ubuntu  you can install it directly with

```
sudo apt-get install mupdf-tools`
```

Last but not least, if you have no intention to install any program, you can use one of the many sites that allow you to do it online.  As more hard alternative there are some python scripts based on PyPDF library available online...

Comment: +1 Since pdf-readers will most likely not support content-workarrounds, the appoach of altering the pdf itself should be the answer.